# Cakephp 3.6.14: Find, update and save records

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have 3 tables: `Tasks [id, name, task_type_id]`, `TaskTypes [id, name]`, `TaskElements [id, name, description, task_type_id, Task_id]`. I want in the `TasksController` (`add` and `edit` functions) to find all the  `task_element` with `task_type_id  != null` and `Task_id == null` and then create new rows with updated `task_id` field .

This is what I have tried till now:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $task = $this->Tasks->patchEntity($task, $this->request->getData());

        //if has specific task type then copy task elements
        if ($this->request->getData('task_type_id') != null){

            $taskElements = TableRegistry::get('TaskElements')->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => ['TaskElements.task_type_id == '=> $this->request->getData('task_type_id')],
                    'limit' => 100
                ])->ToArray();
            debug($taskElements);
            //foreach ($taskEl as $tel) {
            //    $tel->task_id = $id;
            //    $this->Tasks->TaskElements->create();
            //    $this->Tasks->TaskElements->save($tel);
            //}
            
        }

        if ($this->Tasks->save($task)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The task has been saved.'));

            //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
```

But `conditions` are not correct and need to update them. And probably there are more errors in my code which I haven't face yet.

This is the error I get:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1 LIMIT 100' at line 1
>
> SELECT TaskElements.id AS `TaskElements__id`, TaskElements.name AS `TaskElements__name`, TaskElements.description AS `TaskElements__description`, TaskElements.task_type_id AS `TaskElements__task_type_id`, TaskElements.Task_id AS `TaskElements__Task_id` FROM task_elements TaskElements WHERE TaskElements.task_type_id == :c0 LIMIT 100

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query should have "=" in place of "==".

> SELECT TaskElements.id AS TaskElements__id, TaskElements.name AS
>   TaskElements__name, TaskElements.description AS
>   TaskElements__description, TaskElements.task_type_id AS
>   TaskElements__task_type_id, TaskElements.Task_id AS
>   TaskElements__Task_id FROM task_elements TaskElements WHERE
>   TaskElements.task_type_id == :c0 LIMIT 100

you can update like below:

```
$taskElements = TableRegistry::get('TaskElements')->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => ['TaskElements.task_type_id = '=> $this->request->getData('task_type_id')],
                    'limit' => 100
                ])->ToArray();
```

Comment: How I can include also the `Task_id == null` check?

Comment: @aggtr Try-  'conditions' => ['TaskElements.task_type_id = '=> $this->request->getData('task_type_id'), "Task_id IS NULL"],

Answer (score 0):

Do not use like this :

```
TaskElements.task_type_id == '=>
```

Use like this :

```
TaskElements.task_type_id'=>
```

As => already means == because we are already putting it in conditions.

**Tick right if this helps.**